# Manual data normalization in Apollo Client v3

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

In my graphql schema I have two different types: `UserPlaylist` and `ArtistPlaylist`. One type can become the other via mutation. So `UserPlaylist` can become `ArtistPlaylist` and vice versa.

To handle this case on the client I manually replace these types into one common `Playlist` type.
My `InMemoryCache` configuration:

```
const InMemoryCache = new InMemoryCache({
    dataIdFromObject: (object) => {
    switch (object.__typename) {
      case 'UserPlaylist':
      case 'ArtistPlaylist':
        return `Playlist:${object.id}`;

      default: return defaultDataIdFromObject(object);
    }
})
```

The problem is `dataIdFromObject` is deprecated in Apollo Client v3 but I can't seem to find the appropriate replacement.

Comment: ask apollo project maintainers on github issues?

Comment: that was my initial thought, but on their github page they stated that github is not the most suitable place for questions

Comment: I think you are looking for "Type policies" https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#typepolicies. You can define what fields are used to calculate the cache id and define a static field to return 'Playlist'.